# Max timestamp record

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have 2 tables that I would like to join.

I use in CTEs and after i join them.

I would like to select the latest record from Table2 for each student_id (So for each record in Table1 I would I have only one record in table2 to join). the join is by left join to table1.

How could I make it ? I tried many ways and haven't found a solution.

The main table- Table1
Stundet_id
class
comment

Table2

teacher_id
Studnet_id
teacher_name
Recored_timestamp

Comment: can you share what you try ? as I understand , using `MAX(Recored_timestamp)` + `left join`  + `GROUP by Stundet_id`  should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table1
), cte2_aux AS (
    SELECT
        t2.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY student_id
            ORDER BY
                recored_timestamp DESC
        ) rn
    FROM
        table2
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        cte2_aux
    WHERE
        rn = 1
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte2 c2
    LEFT JOIN c1 ON c1.student_id = c2.student_id;
```

Comment: I have an old version of hive and I have got an error while running it.

Comment: This is the error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:78 missing

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a photo that explains this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPa1T.png)